# What is scope of a variable inside ng-repeat block in angular js

Tags: angularjs

what is the scope of showDetails variable. Is it limited to its own li or it affects all the li in the ul.
for complete code refer to http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/

```
ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
<li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
    <h4><a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails " >{{procedure.definition}} </a></h4>
     <div class="procedure-details" ng-show="showDetails">
        <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
     </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of ng-repeat, if you create or use a variable like you did with **showDetails** field , it will create a separate cope for each element type, in this case it will have One for each `li` .

Now for testing the same , You can create a scope variable with same name as `$scope.showDetails` and set it default to ***true***, and then run it . You will see that all details will be visible at time of loading , But when you click again ,it will only affect the depending one.

So at first it will a variable for each li element and provide it the value from scope variable.

Check this fiddel  [Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/c5dof3oj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It means is that procedures variable is limited to the controller sample , it will only be accessible within this controller. Which is providing a synchronized link up with controller to view.

Answer (score 0):

limited to its own li, it will not affect other li under the ul.